# В Moonshine не отображаются картинки

Tags: php, laravel

В админке moonshine (админка для laravel) не отображаются картинки вообще. Я создал новый проект и применились стандартные миграции (к примеру создались миграции moonshine_users и moonshine_user_roles) но когда я создаю пользователя и прикрепляю к нему фотографию, то вижу что фотография не отображается вовсе[image: можно заметить как на месте Avatar неккоректно отображается фото]

Суть в том, что ссылка на storage в папке public создалась, и имеет такой путь -
**C:\ospanel\domains\Moonshine\public\storage\moonshine_users**

В базе пользователь у меня создан корректно и путь до avatar такой -
**moonshine_users/DTYbnxzn2F29nivm7rM2YCd1einQPYZQHzAvX2di.jpg**

В документации немного полазил и ничего не нашёл, но сам факт что в moonshine уже по дефолту были все эти миграции и эта логика, я по факту лишь создал новый проект, и поменять в меню Admins на Users (но по факту и до этих моих изменений фотографии не отображались)

Comment: Там не нужно делать `php artisan storage:link`? [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: ссылка на public уже есть, если вписать php artisan storage:link то консоль выдаст ошибку ERROR  The [C:\OSPanel\domains\Moonshine\public\storage] link already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена легко, всё дело в .env
Вот такая строка была прописана `APP_URL=http://localhost`
Именно из-за неё фотки не выводит, надо чтоб было `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1`
Теперь всё заработало

Comment: Не забудьте прописать php artisan config:clear и php artisan route:clear (на всякий) иначе ничего не заработает!